# How return row when cross apply is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, coalesce, cross-apply

I have a row of data that I would like to add columns to, so I'm cross applying some data.

However, the table that is being applied is sometimes null.

When the applied table is null nothing gets returned.

**Table 1**

```
| a | b | c |
|---+---+---|
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
```

**Table 2**

```
| d | e | f |
|---+---+---|
```

**Query**

```
select top 1 
[col_1] = coalesce([a], [d], '') 
from table_1
cross apply ( select [d], [e] from table_2)
```

**Expected Output**

```
| a | b | c |
|---+---+---|
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
```

**Actual Output**

```
*null*
```

How can I retain the columns from `Table 1` when cross-applying `Table 2` regardless of whether the data is available?

Note: I am trying to use this with a coalesce.

Comment: Use `OUTER APPLY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `outer apply`:

```
select top 1 
[col_1] = coalesce([a], [d], '') 
from table_1
outer apply ( select [d], [e] from table_2)
```